Websocket onmessage not trigger when open next js website on mobile, works fine on desktop
this.socket = new WebSocket(process.env.socket_url);
  this.socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
  this.socket.onopen = () => {

    if (this.socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      this.socket.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          type: "join",
          token,
        })
      );
    }
  };

this.socket.onmessage = async (event) => {
    try {
      // console.log("audio websocket event",event);
      const data = event.data;
      if (data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        this.playAudio(event.data);
      
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log("Websocket -> Error parsing message: ", error);
    }
  };

The same code works when open the website on my laptop but when I open the website on my mobile Android/Apple onmessage does not trigger
